# Switching on class type in Dart

Tags: dart

I'm looking to write a function in a Dart superclass that takes different actions depending on which subclass is actually using it. Something like this:

```dart
class Foo {
  Foo getAnother(Foo foo) {
    var fooType = //some code here to extract fooType from foo;
    switch (fooType) {
      case //something about bar here:
        return new Bar();
      case //something about baz here:
        return new Baz();
    }
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {}

class Baz extends Foo {}
```

where the idea is that I have some object and want to get a new object of the same (sub)class.

The main question is what type should `fooType` be? My first thought was Symbol, which leads to easy case statements like `case #Bar:`, but I don't know how I would populate `fooType` with a Symbol. The only options I can think of are to do something like `Symbol fooType = new Symbol(foo.runtimeType.toString());` but my understanding is that `runtimeType.toString()` won't work when converted to javascript. You could get around that by using Mirrors, but this is meant to be a lightweight library, so those aren't on the table. `Object.runtimeType` returns something of the `Type` class, but I have no idea how to create instances of `Type` I could use for the case statements. Maybe I'm missing some other piece of the Dart library that is better suited for this?

Comment: Special behavior for subclasses, depending on the class: This sounds exactly like what virtual functions are intended to solve. How about having: `class Foo { Foo _createNew() => new Foo(); Foo getAnother(Foo foo) => foo._createNew(); }` and then `class Bar extends Foo { _createNew() => new Bar(); }` and similar for `Baz`?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can use the `runtimeType` in `switch` :

```dart
class Foo {
  Foo getAnother(Foo foo) {
    switch (foo.runtimeType) {
      case Bar:
        return new Bar();
      case Baz:
        return new Baz();
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

In the `case` statements the class name is used directly (AKA *class literal*). This gives a [Type](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:core.Type) object corresponding to the class mentioned. Thus `foo.runtimeType` can be compared with the specified type.

Note that [you can not use generics for now](http://dartbug.com/11923) in *class literals*. Thus, `case List<int>:` is not allowed.

Comment: Amazing! I had no idea you could use class names like that. I have to say, this seems a little like magic. Could you explain more about how this usage works (and maybe about the Type class in general)?

Comment: This doesn't work with `List`, and `Map`, `Set` and probably others.

Comment: I believe this switch case statement with runtimeType will cause error on `pub build` (-> 'case' expression type 'TypeImpl' overrides 'operator =='.). Changing the code to String comparison (`foo.runtimeType.toString()` and `case 'Bar'`) can pass `pub build`.

Comment: does this have any performance ramifications or is it safe to use commonly?

Comment: @AlexandreArdhuin this doesn't work for me. The following example prints "No match. B". https://dartpad.dartlang.org/2012b9264ee9ec79e8c9800d42d3fbef

Comment: Looks like a bug in dart2js. The VM prints B. Feel free to [file an isssue](https://dartbug.com/new)

Comment: Is it impossible to use with generic yet?

Comment: Just a note that `dart analyze` doesn't do exhaustiveness checking on these kinds of switch statements.  For that you need an `enum`.

Comment: This seems not to deal with subclasses. So if you match by Exception, it will not register SessionExpiredException.

Comment: Is this the same as using `is` keyword ? For example `if (fo is Bar) { // do smth} else if (fo is Baz) { // do smth}` or the runtime

Comment: Don't use `runtimeType` in `switch`. [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42802802/10199138)

[Valid dart3.0 Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77299607/10199138)

Answer (score 14):

With flutter 3.0 you can do following:

1. Define class:

```
abstract class LoginActionsEvent {}
 
class LoginActionsCheckConnectionEvent implements LoginActionsEvent {
   const LoginActionsCheckConnectionEvent();
}
```

2. Use switch on type:

```
switch (event) {
  case final LoginActionsCheckConnectionEvent e:
    return _onLoginActionsCheckConnection(e, emit);
  default:
    throw UnimplementedError('Unknown event: $event');
}
```

Comment: This is so handy, thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: This is an unnecessarily complicated example, but good point!