# How do I check type of an object in a switch/case?

Tags: dart

I see in examples this code:

```
if (obj is User) { // do something }
```

I want to check the type of the object in a switch/case flow, and found a property `.runtimeType` of the object:

```
switch (obj.runtimeType) {
    case User:
        print(obj);
        break;
}
```

Is this a correct way to check the type of the object?

Comment: If you find the recent answer in `2023`, follow [Other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77299607/10199138).

The accepted answer of this question is too old.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There is no support in the Dart switch statement for switching by type.
You should use a sequence of `if` tests instead:

```dart
if (obj is User) { 
  print(obj);
} else if (obj is ...) ...
```

I really, really recommend that you never use `runtimeType` for anything.

It can be used to reflect, using `dart:mirrors`, on the type of an object (but you can also just use `reflect(object)` to reflect on the object itself). Apart from that, using `runtimeType` almost always causes otherwise avoidable problems.

The only thing you can do with the `Type` object returned by `runtimeType` is to check it for equality. If you do that (like in the switch above), then you don't correctly handle subtypes. If you ever have a subtype of `User` in your system, like if `User` is an interface and the implementation class is different, or if you mock a `User` for testing, or any number of other causes, then the instance will not have `User` as `runtimeType`, and the code won't recognize it. 
Or maybe it will, because `runtimeType` can be overridden by the user, and any class can choose to return `User`. Testing against `runtimeType` isn't a guarantee that the class is actually the one you check for.

When you compare for type, you should always use `is` because it correctly handles subclasses. 
Subtype substitutability is one of the core ideas of object oriented programming, so you could say that if you use `runtimeType`, you are probably not doing an optimal OO design.

(There are cases where code uses `other.runtimeType == MyClass` in `operator==` to avoid being equal to a subclass instance to avoid the "ColorPoint" problem - but it means that it's impossible to make a subclass or interface implementation (which includes mocks) of that type and have it pass equality checks. That's a very subtle restriction that I would avoid in shared library code. What you do in your own application, that nobody else will depend on, is at least only your problem :smile:).

Comment: There is a really dirty hack, that I'll mention only for completeness, not because you should EVER do it: `try { throw obj; } on User { print(obj); } on SomethingElse { useAsSomethingElse(obj); } on Object { /* default, needed to avoid being uncaught. */ }`

Comment: It looks like it can be done as of 2020
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/35052

Comment: The approach in the linked issue comes with a slew of caveats. It won't work for `List<int>` for example. I'd still not depend on `runtimeType` if at all avoidable. Use `is` tests to test types of objects, that's what it's there for.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to use a switch with Types. (Above Dart2 <= Dart 3.0)

1. With runtimeType
2. With Generic Type

And please be aware that it can not recognize inheritance structure.(extends keyword)

---

**1. With runtimeType**

```dart
main(){
  printWithObject(Animal());
  printWithObject(Cat());
  printWithObject(Dog());
}

class Animal{}

class Dog extends Animal{
}

class Cat extends Animal{
}

void printWithObject(dynamic object){
  print('printWithObject');
  switch(object.runtimeType){
    case Animal:
      print('animal');
      break;
    case Dog:
      print('dog');
      break;
    case Cat:
      print('cat');
      break;
  }
}
```

**2. With Generic Type**

```dart
main(){
  printWithGeneric<Animal>();
  printWithGeneric<Dog>();
  printWithGeneric<Cat>();

  printWithGeneric<Animal?>();
  printWithGeneric<Dog?>();
  printWithGeneric<Cat?>();
}

class Animal{}

class Dog extends Animal{
}

class Cat extends Animal{
}

void printWithGeneric<T>(){
  printSwitchWithType(T);
}

void printSwitchWithType(Type t) {
  print('printSwitchWithType');

  // I have no idea why nullable type
  // is not supported on switch syntax.
  // So I used Type.toString to solve.
  String typeString = t.toString();
  switch(typeString){
    case 'Animal?':
      print('nullable animal');
      break;
    case 'Dog?':
      print('nullable dog');
      break;
    case 'Cat?':
      print('nullable cat');
      break;
  }


  switch(t){
    case Animal:
      print('animal');
      break;
    case Dog:
      print('dog');
      break;
    case Cat:
      print('cat');
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **Pattern matching** with **Dart 3**:

Especially useful for class type checks which will be mocked for tests, because .runtimeType doesn't work there.

```dart
switch (obj) {
  case User():
    print(obj);
    break;
}
```

Matching for specific attributes, you can do sth. like this:

```dart
class Obj {}

class User extends Obj {
  final String name;
  User(this.name);
}

void check(Obj obj) {
  switch (obj) {
    case User(name: 'Foo'):
      print(obj);
      break;
  }
}

void main() {
  final user1 = User('Foo');
  final user2 = User('Bar');

  check(user1);
  check(user2);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

switch string works.

```dart
switchType(Object object) {
  switch (MirrorSystem.getName(new Symbol(object.runtimeType.toString()))) {
    case "Animal":
      print('animal basic');
      break;
    case 'Cat':
      print('Mouse for cat');
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe but this does not answer the question. Sergei wanted to know if it is ok to switch over the RuntimeType or not.

Answer (score -3):

You can create a condition beforehand. Here is an example, as I bumped into this too:

```
String grade;

if(grade is String) {
  grade = grade;
} else {
  grade = null.toString();
}

switch(grade) {
  case "A":
    print("Good");
    break;
  case "B":
    print("Nice");
    break;
  case "null":
    print("Type a string");
    break;
  default:
    print("failed");
    break;
}
```

This way you can check if a value is present or it is an empty string. As mentioned above the easy part is to use a simple If - Else, but otherwise use this.

Comment: Are you concerned that runtimeType might be null?

Answer (score -3):

```
switch (obj.runtimeType.toString()) {
    case 'User':
        print(obj);
        break;
}
```

Comment: pls when posting an answer on SO, make sure you write something and not just drop a piece of code. 
Also, this code does not answer the question: Is it OK to switch over the Runtime Type or not?

Comment: The `.toString()` part is absolutely unnecessary, because you can use type names in the cases instead of strings, but can also result in your code not even working. See https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/obfuscate#caveat