# runtimeType check of generic List object in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to do flow control based on type in Flutter and I came across this. Is this normal?

```
List<Widget> getDetailDisplayWidget() {
  var retval = List<Widget>();

  List<String> test = <String>["something"];
  print(test.runtimeType is List);
  print(test.runtimeType is List<String>);
  print(test.runtimeType == List);

  this._databaseModel.forEach((key, value) {
    switch (value.runtimeType) {
      case String:
        retval.add(SingleValueDetail(
            question: _questionModel[key]["question"],
            label: _questionModel[key]["label"],
            variable: _questionModel[key]["variable"],
            key: key));
        break;
      case Timestamp:
        retval.add(DateValueDetail(
            question: _questionModel[key]["question"],
            variable: _questionModel[key]["variable"],
            key: key));
        break;
      case List:
        retval.add(ListValueDetail(
            question: _questionModel[key]["question"],
            label: _questionModel[key]["label"],
            variable: _questionModel[key]["variable"],
            key: key));
        break;
      default:
        retval.add(ListValueDetail(
            question: _questionModel[key]["question"],
            label: _questionModel[key]["label"],
            variable: _questionModel[key]["variable"],
            key: key));
        //retval.add(Text("Unknown widget type"));
        break;
    }
  });
  return retval;
}
```

Output:

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device iPhone SE...
Restarted application in 1,710ms.
flutter: false
flutter: false
flutter: false
```

Dart version:

```
Dart VM version: 2.7.2 (Mon Mar 23 22:11:27 2020 +0100) on "macos_x64"
```

Comment: It is not `test.runtimeType is List` but `test is List`.

Comment: About using switch statement for types, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42802802/1953515

Comment: thanks for a fast reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the type of a List by simply using if statement like

```
if (test is List<String>) {
}
```

If you print `print(test.runtimeType)` it will give you `List<String>`. One way you can use the runtimeType like this.

```
 switch(test.runtimeType.toString()) {
      case "List<String>":
        print(true);
        break;
      default:
        print(false);
    }
```

I prefer the first option. You don't know `toString` method implementation can be changed any time.

Comment: You should properly also read https://stackoverflow.com/a/42802802/1953515 about why you should almost never use the value from `runtimeType`.

Comment: I will avoid it from now but curious for me was when printing runtimeType gives me List<String> as output. And checking it against generic type resulted in false. Why the attribute exist in first place.

Comment: When you print `runtimeType` it actually give you the `toString` method implementation output. But when you call `runtimeType`  it return `Type` object which is not equal to List<String>.  But you can use it check if two object has the same `runtimeType` Like     ```var hello = "";
    var world = "";

    print(hello.runtimeType == world.runtimeType);```