# Access variables from inherited class by declaring parent object Dart Flutter

Tags: dart

I have a model, Post, that is abstract. I have 3 child classes, call them XPost, YPost, and ZPost.

Post looks like

```
abstract class Post {
  final String userUid;
  final String documentId;
  final String type;
}
```

and let's say XPost has an additional variable called "data". My question is, how can I access the data variable by creating a Post object.

```
Post post;
post = await _database.getPost(postID);
print(post.data); //it says data isn't defined for post class
```

I want to keep the post as the abstract type so I can decide at runtime which type of post (X, Y, Z) it is.

Comment: If you *know* that `_database.getPost` will return an `XPost`, then you can do an explicit cast.

Comment: Like: `post = (await _database.getPost(postID)) as XPost;`. Or you can use an if-statement to ask like `if (post is XPost) { print(post.data); }` since this will automatically promote the variable type.

Comment: Yeah, I switch on the "type" variable and return XPost from the _database.getPost call, but it still won't let me access it because the type of post is Post, not XPost.

Comment: Try `print((post as XPost).data);`

Answer (score 0):

Method `getPost` returns `Post` so without casting, you're not going to be able to access properties on inherited classes.

If you expect different types of post to be returned by `getPost` you could do something like this

```
switch (post.runtimeType) {
  case XPost:
    print((post as XPost).data);
  case YPost:
    print((post as YPost).someotherfield);
}
```

Comment: Never use `runtimeType`. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42802802/1953515

Comment: An example of the problem: https://gist.github.com/julemand101/3bb346bab97a0745a534e6a8f2cd416b . Map's runtimeType is `_InternalLinkedHashMap` so the check does not work. But `if (post is Map)` will work because `_InternalLinkedHashMap` does implement `Map`.